# How to pronounce "twenty" correctly?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, numbers, phonology

Well, I usually say "twenny" instead of "twenty" (not "twendy" even). I recently noticed that I never heard the same from any native english speakers during any talks I ever had with them.

Recently I had a brief search on the 'net and it seems that it is somehow okay to say "twenny", but it might look the least correct pronunciation for most of the people, or they might think you have strange accent, etc.

So, my question is, is there any good reference which clearly proves saying "twenny" instead of "twenty" is totally correct or wrong?

P.S. You're most welcome to write your very personal opinion if you don't know any good references.

**Update**

I've already looked at the major dictionaries and didn't find any of them lists "twenny" in their pronunciation's section, however I'm sure that I didn't made that up, but I heard that while ago. Maybe in a movie, maybe from someone, and that's why I'm looking for the answer.

Comment: okay guys, why down vote? just say what's wrong with that? thanks.

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary? As it stands, your question lacks sufficient prior research and is probably considered to be _general reference_.

Comment: @coleopterist yes, I had a look at all the major dictionaries, not of them listed "twenny" in their pronunciations, however would you agree with me that there are people (mostly native english speakers) whose saying "twenny" instead of "twenty"? that's why I look to see if it's totally acceptable or wrong.

Comment: If you looked in dictionaries, you will want to add this information to your question along with relevant links or excerpts. Dictionaries tend to be reasonably reliable sources when it comes to pronunciations. You can also try other sites such as forvo.com. In any event, demonstrating prior research will encourage more users to answer your question.

Comment: @coleopterist thanks for the answer and I'll look at forvo.com as well. As I said in the OP, I couldn't found any proof which clearly says it's correct or wrong and that's why I'm asking such a question here, just to find a proof.

Comment: I'd only associate the 'twenny' pronunciation with a New York wise guy

Comment: For what it's worth, "twenny" is absolutely ubiquitous in Southern Ontario (whence I hail), and it wouldn't occur to me to pronounce "twenty" otherwise in _any_ context. But then again, we do (in)famously call the capital city of Ontario /ˈtrɒnoʊ/...

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić so I can consider that as kind of rare local accent ...

Comment: If one is going to ask (**or** answer) a question about pronunciation here, one should use [standard English phonemic notation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf), not made-up spellings or 18th-century notation. English writing does not reproduce sounds, and trying to make it do so is a recipe for still more confusion.

Comment: I don't think /ˈtwɛni/ — John Lawler is right, this is precisely why IPA and its derivatives exist — is absolutely universal in North America, but I would imagine that it's common enough.

Comment: God help us all if somebody asks how to pronounce "oysters".

Comment: [Limmy's Show: twenty's plenty](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmhLS3DCoU0&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DSmhLS3DCoU0&gl=GB)

Comment: First learn how to pronounce it distinctly.  Then, once you are familiar with its usage, and with English in general, allow your words to "flow" naturally.

Comment: I wrote the phonetic spellings of 'counter', 'internet' and 'international' respectively. *Counner* -> 'counter' (it does have a t).

Comment: @Decapitated Soul: I think the t-less pronunciation of *twenny* is more common than the t-less pronunciation of *counter*, *internet*, *international*. But this is just a vague impression; I don't have any data.

Comment: @PeterShor: I don't know for sure, but almost all of my American friends pronounce counter as if it were *counner*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The stop in syllables that end in a homorganic nasal-plus-stop cluster (in English, these clusters are /mb, mp, nd, nt, ŋɡ, ŋk/) is often elided. Word-final /-mb/ and  /-ŋɡ/ never occur in Modern English, for example, although their dumb Middle English spellings hang around.

Final /-nd/ **does** occur, though not always, but it's frequently neutralized with /-nt/, especially after a stressed vowel and preceding an unstressed one. As in *twenty*.

This interacts with the neutralization of /d/ and /t/ in the same environment; in American English, both go to [ɾ], as in *betting* and *bedding*, which differ -- if at all -- only in the allophonic vowel length of stressed /ɛ/ in the first syllable of *bedding*.

**Upshot**: In American English, /'twəni/ is the normal pronunciation, /'twɛni/ is somewhat more formal and careful, and /'twɛnti/ is fastidiously careful.

Comment: Thanks John, may I ask you a reference for "In American English, /'twəni/ is the normal pronunciation". Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may quote me.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at the PDF file you referenced on the comments as well. I guess I will get there soon, thanks again.

Comment: Charles-James Bailey in his "Four low-level pronunciation rules of Northern States English" says that  /'twɛni/  > /'twəni/ has to do with the retraction of light nuclei. He also links this further with pen-pin merger. Of course, I am not presenting the whole picture of what he says. What do you think of that? I can share his paper with you, if you dont have it.

Comment: I'm not presenting the whole picture, either, not in ten lines. C-J is correct; there's a whole lot going on here. But this is not LOLPhonology.

Comment: I think of /'twɛni/ as the normal pronunciation, and never say /'twəni/ (although it doesn't sound wrong to me, so I have probably heard it). The first vowel clearly depends on the dialect of American English.

Comment: Does this happen even when the stop is unvoiced? 'hunt', 'dump', 'junk' all pronounce the last stop. Isn't that almost always true? What about the 'finger/singer' difference? Also, what if you're from Long gIsland?

Comment: If the stop is unreleased you can't tell whether it's voiced or not.

Comment: Isn't /ə/ used in unstressed syllables only? It sounds like /ˈtwanti/ to my non-native ears.

Comment: In American English, there's only one central vowel phoneme /ə/, which has a stressed allophone [ʌ], and a number of unstressed allophones, ranging from [ə] through [ɨ].

Answer (score 10):

[Lexico on BrE](https://www.lexico.com/definition/twenty): Pronunciation /ˈtwɛnti/
[Lexico on AmE](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/twenty): Pronunciation /ˈtwɛn(t)i/

Speakers of English may get lazy and not articulate the second *t* sound clearly, or at all. However it is non-standard. There are some dialects (for example, London and the Thames Estuary) where it is reasonably common. Because it is non-standard, it appears in writing only when actually representing this speech, as indicated in the [Wiktionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/twenny).

Comment: Pretty sure this is normal for almost all the XXXty-YYY numbers in most speakers when not being careful.  Listen to a little kid count up to 100 out loud as fast as they can.  See what happens?  Now do it yourself.  Same thing, right?

Comment: thanks Andrew for explanation, Wiktionary reference and mentioning Eye dialect, I learned something new! :)

Comment: @tchrist It's easy with twen'y and seven'y and possibly nine'y, more difficult with eighty. That would be more likely to resemble /d/.

Comment: This answer needs fixing. (1) the ODO has been replaced by Lexico, so the link is broken and (2) [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/twenty) now shows a /t/-less pronunciation of *twenty*. Dropping the /t/ is common enough in the U.S. that I'd hesitate to call it non-standard.

Comment: @PeterShor If you find a broken link, feel free to fix it. I'm afraid I'm not trawling through every answer I ever wrote to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't entirely agree with John Lawler's answer, insofar that it seems to suggest that there is little difference between the pronunciation of "twenty" and the pronunciation of any other word with /nt/, or of any word with /nd/. I do believe that the use of a reduced pronunciation without the sound [t] is more common for *twenty* than for a word like *winter,* and more common for *winter* than for a word like *grunting* (see my answer to the ELL question [Can we drop the T sound in word grunting in American English?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115907/can-we-drop-the-t-sound-in-word-grunting-in-american-english/115943#115943)) And words with /nd/ don't necessarily show the same kind of reduction.

Also, **mb, mp, ŋɡ, ŋk** behave even less similarly, so I wouldn't group them together with **nt** or **nd**.

It's impossible to show that any pronunciation of *twenty* is "totally correct" or "wrong" because these words don't have any clear and universally accepted definition in this context. The pronunciation without a [t] is attested in the [Oxford Dictionaries entry for US English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/twenty): it gives the pronunciation in IPA as /ˈtwɛn(t)i/, which is just an abbreviated way of writing "/ˈtwɛnti/ or /ˈtwɛni/". As described in this [answer by Greg Lee](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/226221/77227), at least some speakers are supposed to use a nasal flap sound [ɾ̃] in words like *twenty.* Greg Lee says that he also uses a nasal flap in words like *penny,* but in a comment,  Janus Bahs Jacquet suggested that some speakers might maintain a slight distinction by using [ɾ̃] in *twenty* but [n] in *penny.*

Greg Lee also left a comment below that post with an interesting citation about the pronunciation of /nd/ vs. /nt/ in this kind of context:

> Stampe has pointed out that for some midwestern speech, there is a level of casualness where "candor" and "canner" differ just in having [n] in the first and nasal flap in the second. The [n] in "candor" comes by an assimilation of the [d] to preceding [n], giving [nn], then a simplification of the geminate.

Comment: I’m pretty sure I’m one of those people. In normal speech, my _twenty_ (especially in _twenty-XXX_ compounds) is very likely to be [ˡtʍɛɾ̃i ~ ˡtʍəɾ̃i]. In rapid or tired speech, frequently even [ˡtʍəɹ̃i], with the /nt/ cluster becoming a nasalised, centralised, postalveolar approximate with no contact at all (I might even write it [ˡtʍə.ɨ̞̯̃i], if it weren’t so diacritically overloaded).

Comment: (Jinx – you were editing as I was wrestling with typing IPA on my phone!)

Answer (score 0):

Twenty with the 't' pronounced is more of a British (Colonial English) way to say it whereas 'Twenny' is American English (native speakers). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In most American accents, words like *internet, international, counter* etc., are pronounced as if they were *innernet, innernational* and *counner* respectively.

In all these words, the *n* is at the end of one syllable while the *t* starts the next syllable:

- IN.TER.NET
- IN.TER.NATIO.NAL
- COUN.TER.

So it's not strange to hear 'twenty' being pronounced *twen-nee*.

It's a feature of 'informal' speech and is increasingly common in the US.
As far as I'm aware, there's no rule for when to pronounce or drop the t in these words.

So I assume whenever a syllable ends with an *n* and another syllable starts with a *t* (mostly an unstressed syllable), the *t* is often dropped.
Don't expect every American to drop their t's. It also depends on the context.

Normally when we're pronouncing a nasal (/m n/ etc), the airflow comes out through nasal cavity; however, when there's a following stop (/p t k/ etc), the airflow needs to be stopped and then released through the oral cavity, perhaps Americans find it hard to do that? I don't know.

Comment: Answer to another question, merged with this one.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the answers via OED:

Twenty

> Pronunciation:
>
> Brit. /**ˈtwɛnti**/
>
> U.S. /**ˈtwɛn(t)i**/

Depending upon regional accents,

(i) **ˈtwɛni** is heard in the UK, often with a short glottal stop between the n and i

(ii) /**ˈtwɛnti**/ may be heard in the US.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to native speakers https://quizword.net/de-en/sentences/search/?query=twenty This is the best way to learn how to pronounce a word.

Comment: That's good but it's the same U.S. speaker every time.  [Here's a selection](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/twenty). Only the US Southern version says "twenny" all the others clearly pronounce the "t".

Comment: ... Yes; this answer is essentially a misquote – giving sound advice but then referencing an inadequate sample. Then there's the question _What should be pointed out as constituting poor speech?_ And the follow-up _Who is qualified to decide this?_