# Pronunciation of "twenty" in US English

Tags: pronunciation

I often hear how people from the United States pronounce "twenty" as "twonny" in movies, etc. Why? Is this an alternative pronunciation?

Comment: Hugely related and probably a duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96576/how-to-pronounce-twenty-correctly

Comment: How can it be a duplicate? That guy asks about another pronunciation

Comment: Do you mean "twonny" to rhyme with "money", "pony", "tawny",  "Lonnie", or "Suwannee"?

Comment: I mean "twonny" like in "want"

Comment: It is an accent. "Twonny" sounds like northeastern US like maybe an Italian-American influenced accent? "Twenny" / "Twanky" is more slangy but the former is still accent-informed.

Comment: No one in the world ever rhymes *twenty* with *Johnny*.

Comment: @szx: "want" rhyming with "hunt" or "want" rhyming with "avant" or maybe "want" rhyming with "font"? There are enough regional variations of American English that spelling things without using phonetic symbols is very confusing.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't know that anybody rhymes *twenty* with anything but *penny* or *plenty*, but in some places, like Chicago, they pronounce all of *twenty*, *penny* and *plenty* funny.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a native speaker but I've been learning mostly American English for a long time now and the so-called *flapped t* is widely used by American English speakers in fluent speech.

That's probably what **szx** heard. So *twenty* becomes \'twɛni\ to rhyme with 'penny'. But my guess is that in really fast speech it can even become more like *tw'nny* resulting in something like  \'twɐni\  or \'twʌni\ which can probably be transcribed as 'twonny'.

The Oxford Advanced American Dictionary:

> **[twenty](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/twenty)** *number*/ˈtwɛnti; ˈtwɛni; ˈtwʌni/

For more information on 'flapped t' refer to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervocalic_alveolar_flapping):

> The cluster [nt] can also be flapped/tapped; the IPA symbol for a nasal tap is [ɾ̃]. As a result, in quick speech, words like winner and winter can become homophonous.

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly a combination of the accent in some parts, though I don't know offhand where those places would be, and local 'shorthand' type pronunciations. As long as you recognise it as twenty though, in the context of the movie, there shouldn't be a problem.