# So called "tap", or "nap"

Tags: pronunciation, flapping

I'm interested in so called "tap" in american English. I've read a tap occurs in a word "twenty". I've heard this word in the internet and I've noticed a t is not pronounced or is pronounced simply as a t. Can you explain me? Besides, does a tap occur in words: "ended", "regarded", "internet", "interview" and why?

Comment: Not all Americans speak the same. Some Americans say *twenty*, some say *twenny*, and some use an [alveolar nasal flap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_flap#Alveolar_nasal_flap), which sounds more like *twenny* than a regular alveolar flap, which would sound like *tweddy*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether it's a tap or a flap, but I'll call it a flap. "twenty" has a nasal flap (same as in "penny"), and the theory I learned from David Stampe is that the phonological derivation is approximately /twɛnti/ -> (aspiration, regressive vowel nasalization, syllabication) [tʰwɛ̃nt.i] -> (delay alveolar articulation) [tʰwɛ̃t.i] -> (flapping) [tʰwɛ̃ɾ.i] -> (progressive sonorant nasalization) [tʰwɛ̃ɾ̃.i].

Does a flap occur in "ended"?  No.  The first d is preceded by a consonant, n, which prevents flapping.  That n is not lost, as it is in "twenty", because the following d is voiced.

Does a flap occur in "regarded"? Yes.  d flaps after a vowel or vowel-like non-syllabic like r, w, y (not l, though).

Does a flap occur in "internet"?  Yes, the first t becomes nasal flap, but the second n doesn't flap, since it's before a stressed vowel and hence in syllable onset.

Does a flap occur in "interview"?  Yes.  This case is like "twenty".

Comment: Hmm … I think _penny_ is a slightly different kettle of fish. I (usually) have a flap in both _twenty_ and _regarded_, but not in _penny_. At least not in significantly more rapid and slurred speech than is required for the others—the same stage of rapidness and slurriness where _ended_ also gets a flap. I’m sure there’s a scale of ‘_penny_ flappiness variation’ between speakers, but I don’t think it’s quite parallel to the _twenty_ scale.

Comment: Stampe has pointed out that for some midwestern speech, there is a level of casualness where "candor" and "canner" differ just in having [n] in the first and nasal flap in the second.  The [n] in "candor" comes by an assimilation of the [d] to preceding [n], giving [nn], then a simplification of the geminate.  This works for me, but it doesn't surprise me in the least if your speech differs.

Comment: Well, that particular example doesn’t work for me at all, because both words are too uncommon and high-register for me to ever assimilate at all, I think. If I got to the level of casualness where I’d assimilate one, I’d assimilate them both equally. But I definitely have levels of casualness where _inner_ and _inter(net)_ differ only in the former having [n] and the latter [ɾ̃], and my gut feeling is that that’s a fairly common level, cross-country, to have, viz., that /nt/ is flapped before /n/.