# How to pronounce "seventeen" and "seventy"?

Tags: pronunciation

As titled, both of these words always sound similar to me. Sometimes, the stress of these words will shift. For example, "seventeen" will say "SEVENteen". I am not sure whether it is correct or not. If so, and why?

Comment: They are indeed very similar, but the pronunciation of the *n* at the end of *seventeen* should allow you to make a distinction between the two words.

Comment: In American English, 17 is pronounced /sɛvṇ'tin/, with an aspirated /t/ followed by a stressed tense vowel  on the last syllable. 70, on the other hand, is pronounced /'sɛvṇi/, with stress on the first syllable and a minimum last syllable /i/. The stress is the most important difference, but the final syllables are quite different.

Comment: A dictionary will typically contain the difference in pronunciation. Please specify which dictionaries you have consulted, what they said, and why that was of no help. As to the question "I would like to know how many ways to pronounce these two words?", it is entirely unclear what that even means. Please clarify.

Comment: John, how is 70 pronounced sev ni?  I have never heard that...it completely misses the t and is a two syllable sound...even if the t is "light."

Comment: @michael_timofeev The /t/ is very commonly completely missed, yes. Most commonly, the /nt/ in _seventy_ is reduced to either /n/ or /ɾ̃/ (a nasalised tap). But what John wrote, /ˈsεvn̩i/ is three syllables, not two: the little vertical stroke under the /n/ means it’s syllabic, so it’s basically /sεv.n.i/ with dots separating the syllables.

Comment: I couldn't see the dot under the n on my screen...looked like dust.  Any examples of this 70 pronunciation online or somewhere?  I must admit that since I'm a language teacher I do try and pronounce more clearly but I do retain the America accent...I don't mumble and slur my words as much...still, I hear the d there.  My students are always complaining about this problem of number pronunciation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thanks...now I'm getting the hang of things around here...been dealing with the Typhoon in Taipei.

Answer (score 7):

When speaking, you can distinguish between them more easily by stressing a different syllable:

- 17 = sev en TEEN
- 70 = SEV en tee

Comment: Plus, the /t/ is usually not pronounced in 70, so it sounds like "sevenee". But you're right, the stress is the significant clue.

Comment: In my neck of the woods,we say sevendy, not sevenee.

Comment: I agree with Tim; 70 is pronounced with a distinct /d/ sound and it's how I teach students to say the "ty" numbers to avoid ambiguity.  I'm not an expert on regional accents so I'd like to know.

Comment: Ah, perhaps in connected speech the /d/ or /t/ in "seventy" is barely heard. Must watch more American movies.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That's exactly right. If you listen to American children counting, the "sevenny" pronunciation is by far the most common one. This reduction of /ent/ is well documented; it also occurs in *twenty*, which comes out sounding like "twenny" in connected speech by (these) native speakers. It's important to remember that children everywhere learn their native tongue by ear not by eye.

Comment: @tchrist I think the t or d in 70 is there-- we're just not hearing it.  What about 30, 40, etc?

Comment: @michael_timofeev [ˈtʰɛ̃ˈtʰwɛniˈθɝɾiˈfo˞ɾiˈfɪɾiˈsɪɾiˈsɛvniˈeɪ̯ɾiˈnɐĩ̯ɾijəˈhʌ̃d͡ʒɻʷəd̚]

Comment: @tchrist so you're pronouncing Thirty without a "t?" Like Scottland?

Comment: @michael_timofeev Hardly. It's a flap, the same as in *rider, writer, latter*. You cannot talk about a "t". That doesn't make sense because you're talking about letters not sounds. North American English flaps. That's what I wrote.

Comment: @tchrist well without hearing you say this in a natural setting, it's hard to discuss.  Maybe my pronunciation is more clear than most because I've lived in foreign countries for much of my life.  Getting back to the OP, how would you advise them to hear and pronounce 17 and 70?

Comment: @michael_timofeev I already wrote how it's done. Did you not read it, or do you just  not understand IPA? That's how you talk about these things. It's the international standard used by linguists and students alike.

Comment: @tchrist yeah, I can read it.

Comment: This answer is not intended not go into depth about how people _do_ pronounce these words. It is intended to recommend concisely a way to pronounce these words so that (1) every English speaking listener will understand the speaker and (2) it is easy to hear the difference. Refer to @tchrist's answer for a perfectly fine comprehensive explanation.

Comment: @tchrist Wait, _fifty_ and _sixty_ rhyme with _fiddy_ and _city_ to you? I though that was pretty exclusively Deep South! (I would have though people who pronounce 60 like that would also pronounce 70 with no /v/, as /sɛni/ or /sɛɾi/ (can't type nasalised epsilon and tap on phone).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Wow, somebody was actually paying attention. No, not normally; only when I’m a little kid trying to count fast for hide-and-go-seek. :)

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:** *Seventeen* is /sɛvən**ˈtin**/ but *seventy* is /**ˈsɛv**ənti/. <sub><sup>(However, those are not **phonetic** transcriptions.)</sup></sub>

#### Edit

Regarding your edit, you are right than the stress varies in *seventeen*. Normally its last syllable is stressed,  but sometimes other factors can change this.

For example, when it forms part of a recited sequence of numbers like when counting up to twenty, stress normally shifts to the first syllable.  That way the part that varies dominates.

---

## Stress and Aspiration

The honest answer to “how many ways do these words get said” is a great many. However, both words have a cluster of related pronunciations that vary only slightly between region, speaker, register, and environment or context.

The common pronunciations in General American are:

#### 17: *seventeen*

Phonemic /sɛvən**ˈtin**/ may be realized as phonetic [ˌsɛvɪ̈nˈtʰiːn], [ˌsɛvəⁿˈtʰiːn], [ˌsɛvn̩ˈtʰiːn]  (amongst other things).

#### 70: *seventy*

Phonemic /**ˈsɛv**ənti/ may be realized as phonetic [ˈsɛvn̩di], [ˈsɛvəɾ̃i], [ˈsɛvɾ̃i], ['sɛvṇi] (amongst other things).

---

As you see, these two words differ from each other in multiple ways. What stands out most is that the /t/ phoneme in *seventeen* gets pronounced as an aspirated [tʰ] because it is stressed, while in *seventy* that same /t/ phoneme either reduces to an unaspirated and flapped [ɾ]  in careful speech — or, more commonly, is lost altogether.

So **stress** and **aspiration** are your main distinguishing features here.

However, those aspects can sometimes be hard to catch in connected speech or over faulty connections. Indeed, over the telephone — especially when one or both parties are stuck using inaudibly supercompressed cell transmission — it is often difficult even for native speakers to distinguish between *sixty* and *sixteen*, or between *seventy* and *seventeen*.

For more details about the reduction of phonemic /ɛnt/ in this context, see [Prof. Lawler’s answer to “How to pronounce *twenty* correctly?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/96576), in which he concludes with:

> **Upshot:** In American English, /'twəni/ is the normal pronunciation, /'twɛni/ is somewhat more formal and careful, and /'twɛnti/ is fastidiously careful.

The same applies here.  Context can help with this if it’s there; for example, someone even quickly reciting the numbers by tens would always be understood because the *‑teen* versions wouldn’t make sense there.  Imagine kids rapidly counting off by tens while playing hide-and-go-seek; their sequence of:

- *ten, twenty, thirty, forty, ﬁfty, sixty, seventy, eight, ninety, a hundred*

becomes a somewhat blurred but completely unambiguous:

- [ˈtʰɛ̃ˈtʰwɛniˈθɝɾiˈfo˞ɾiˈfɪɾiˈsɪɾiˈsɛvniˈeɪ̯ɾiˈnɐĩ̯ɾijəˈhʌ̃d͡ʒɻʷəd̚]

---

### Better Questions

The more background you give in your question, the better we can answer it. I cannot tell from your profile what your country of origin or native language might be.

- It may be that you are not used to English sounds reducing under fast speech rules; this reduction happens not only to [vowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English) (virtually always) but also sometimes to [consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision#English), including here.
- It may also be that you are not hearing the different phonetic allophones of the same underlying English phonemes as “falling into the same bucket”, so to speak.

But without more information from you, we cannot guess what more you need to know for this to become clearer for you.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for that. I couldn't decide whether to mark the reduced vowel or the reduced consonant for nasalization, so I ended up going with an alternate representation that may have left something to be desired.

Comment: I agree that twenty is reduced to twenni however I just can't agree that seventy gets this as well.  Also, lately I have seen several posts in which people claim that native speakers have trouble understanding each other in various situations...I have never experienced this and I don't have conversations in ivory towers.  I also think that the difference between 17 and 70 is a timing issue as well as sound reduction and stress.  This goes for all the teens and ty parallels.

Comment: @michael_timofeev Sometimes it does; sometimes it doesn’t. As with most things in language, not only do multiple possibilities exist, it is impossible to select any one of them as being somehow “right” and consign the others to being somehow “wrong”. We can only document what occurs.